Error between two solutions of the same complementarity system with different data
Let $\eta_i \in L^{\infty}([t_0,t_f], \mathbb{R}^{n_c})$, $i=1,2$, be solutions of the respective complementarity system
$$
\eta_i(t) \geq 0, \; c_i(t)\leq 0, \; \eta_i^\top c_i(t) = 0.
$$
I want to quantify the error $|| \eta_1 - \eta_2 ||$ in terms of the difference of the data $|c_1-c_2|$ where the norm could be the 2-norm or the $\infty$-norm.
I started with writing the complementarity system equivalently as
$$
\eta - c - \sqrt{\eta^2 +c^2} = 0.
$$
(using the Fischer-Burmeister function).
Subtracting and re-arranging gives
\begin{align*}
    \eta_1 - \eta_2 &= c_1-c_2 +  \sqrt{\eta_1^2 +c_1^2}-\sqrt{\eta_2^2 +c_2^2} \\ 
&= c_1-c_2 + \frac{(\eta_1+\eta_2)(\eta_1-\eta_2) - (c_1+c_2)(c_1-c_2)}{\sqrt{\eta_1^2+c_1^2} + \sqrt{\eta_2^2+c_2^2}}
\end{align*}
and now I am stuck. I expected this to be simple. Does anyone know how to proceed from here or has a different ansatz? I appreciate any hint and help!
